# AngularJS and an async function inside of a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am having this issue with an async function. The point is that the "execution" is not waiting for the return of `NotificationService.confirm` callback.

I mean, that shows a PhoneGap alert, but it's not waiting for evaluate which button pressed the user. So, you can see in the console output `undefined` instead of false/true/3 values

[EDIT]

This is the code proposed by Maxim Shoutin, but it isn't working yet:

**NotificationController.js**

```
angular.module('app').controller("NotificationController", function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.cancel_button = function() {
      var confirm = NotificationService.confirm("Do you want to confirm?", 'Yes!');

      confirm.then(function(result) {
        console.log('Confirm: ' + result);
        if(confirm)   $location.path('/menu');
      }, function(result) {
        console.log('No data returned');
      })
    }

   /* Additional controller code... */
}
```

**NotificationService.js**

```
angular.module('app').factory("NotificationService", function() {

  // Callback function
  var onConfirm = function(button) {
    console.log('Callback function called!!!');
    if(button == 1)       return false;
    else if(button == 2)  return true;
    else if(button == 3)  return 3;
    else                  return false; // dismissed without press button
  };

 return {
     confirm : function(alert_msg, title, buttonsArray) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if(buttonsArray == null) {
             buttonsArray = ['Cancel', 'OK'];
        }

         var data = navigator.notification.confirm(
                        alert_msg,      // message
                        onConfirm,      // callback
                        title,          // title
                        buttonsArray    // buttonsArray
                    );

         deferred.resolve(data);
         return deferred.promise;
      }
  }
}
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

`> Confirm: undefined` (**BEFORE** user pressed the button)

`> Callback function called!!!`  (**AFTER** user pressed the button)

Comment: Example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VfqJkJO2n7FFLWoTO2Bp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `NotificationService.confirm("Do you want to confirm?", 'Yes!');` returns promise (a.e. async).

So it should be something like:

```
var confirm = NotificationService.confirm("Do you want to confirm?", 'Yes!');

// now confirm is a promise
confirm.then(function (result) {
            console.log('Confirm: ' + confirm);

            if(confirm)   $location.path('/round/actual');                                    
                    }, function (result) {
                        alert("Error: No data returned");
                    })
```

Only for demo we can use `$timeout` to simulate async call:

```
app.factory('NotificationService', function($q,$timeout) {

  // Callback function
  var onConfirm = function(button) {

    var state;

    console.log('Callback function called!!!');
    if(button == 1)       state = 'working!';
    else                  state = false; // dismissed without press button

    return state;
  };


  var factory =  {
     confirm : function(alert_msg, title, buttonsArray) {

       var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function () {
         var state =  onConfirm(1); // simulate call callback after 3 sec
         deferred.resolve(state);
       }, 3000);

       return deferred.promise;
      }
  }
  return factory;
});
```

Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kyJoe5NnZV9y0HMTIiyY?p=preview)</kbd>

In your case, since `navigator.notification.confirm` uses callback so you can try to return *resolve* from callback.

Comment: It's almost done, but it's unfinished yet. I mean, if I do a console.log(result) the output is UNDEFINED yet because the execution is not being "paused" until user press a button. I updated the ask with the code

Comment: Hmm, in Plunker, the `data` is single method but it should be some value like array or model that you get by async way

Comment: I can't add the navigator.notification because it's from Cordova.js and it does not work here. Cause of that I let that function. You can modify with anything simple to test. Thanks you for your time!

Comment: see my edit i posted, i saw in docs of phonegap that `navigator.notification` uses callback only

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're resolving the promise before the data has actually come back. You need to give your `onConfirm` function access to the promise that `NotificationService.confirm` is handing back, and only call `resolve` inside there.

Answer (score 1):

`$q` works by letting methods have a reference to an answer that may not exist yet, and letting them register callbacks to be run when the answer is done.  That means that if you call `defer()` in the same code block as `resolve()`, you're not really using the promise asynchronously, since you resolve it immediately after it was made.

You need to remnove `deferred.resolve(data)` from your `confirm` function block, and put it in your callback function instead.  `resolve()` should **always** go in a callback function of some sort, because callback functions are how you wait for an asynchronous event.  If you can resolve a promise in the getter, then it's not really asynchronous!

Then, change your `onConfirm` method to look like this:

```
var onConfirm = function(button) {
  console.log('Callback function called!!!');
  var result= false;

  // if(button == 1)    default case

  if(button == 2)  { result = true; }
  else if(button == 3)  { result = 3; }

  // else               default case

 deferred.resolve(result);
};
```

Now, we don't resolve the promise until we're in the notificaiton callback, which means the user has made their selection, and we resolve it with the user's decision.

Finally, you'll notice that if `onConfirm` is outside of your service, it won't have access to the `deferred` object it needs to resolve.  Move `onConfirm` into your `confirm` function so it will have closure access to that variable.